# How to find the bit error rate when each bit of information is transmitted multiple times?

Tags: python, decode, encode

I am measuring the bit error rate of a channel. The sender sends a 01 sequence. The transmit cycle of the sender is 1000ms, which means constant modulation within 1000ms. The receiver measures every 200ms. the ideal measurement result is 000001111100000. The receiver restores the 010 sent by the sender.
However, due to the influence of noise, etc., the receiver cannot measure the bit information 5 times.The receiver actually received 00100110100001。Human eyes can also find out that the sender sent 010, but how to let the computer to distinguish.

The problem is: Although the sender’s sending cycle is 5 times that of the receiver, the receiver may have measured less than 5 times. Therefore I cannot decode every 5 times.

If I decode based on each flip, it is still unreasonable. This is because there are problems with bit flipping, bit loss, and bit increase during transmission. Therefore, both 00100 and 0010,000100 should be decoded as 0.

How should I find the bit error rate?
Does python provide some practical packages to solve this problem?

Thanks.